# How do I install Flutter app on Android phone?

Tags: flutter, installation

I couldn't install flutter app on my android phone. How can I do it? I can run by usb debugging However I want to install it on my phone. Can someone help me please?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: connect your phone with usb and enable developer options after that you are able to run your app in a device. after that you need to run your app using    flutter run    commando

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect your Android device to your computer with a USB cable.
2. Enter **cd [project]**.
3. Run **flutter install**.

Source: [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#install-an-apk-on-a-device)

Answer (score 2):

Build and install a large APK for all architectures:

```bash
flutter build apk 
flutter install --device-id <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>
```

Build and install smaller APK for a specific architecture:

```bash
flutter build apk -split-per-abi

# check output from last command for paths

flutter install 
  --device-id <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> 
  --use-application-binary=<APK-PATH>
```

List all available device IDs by running:

`flutter install`

Answer (score 1):

If you use IntelliJ Idea (it should also work on Android Studio), you can go to

**Build -> Flutter -> Build APK,** (in the menu bar)

and after building, your apk will appear in

**build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk,**

just send the file to your phone and install, your phone will probably tell you not do download cause it isn't checked and secured or something, just ignore and install anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the app to get the apk. For building apk use this command in console: `flutter build apk` and if you want to build your apk in smaller size then use this command in console: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`.

After building apk you will find it in  `[project]\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk` here.

If you don't want to build apk and just want to test your app you can run it in profile mode by using this command in console:  `flutter run --profile`.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio under the tools-> build -> build apk will create and app for you and you can get and the output location will show you after the builing  the app